# Usar dados de um array de uma classe em outra

Tags: java, array, orientação-a-objetos

Como eu posso usar o array `palavra_vetor` em outra classe.

```
public class Lista{
   String palavras_leitura [] = new String[50];
   String palavra_vetor[] = new String [4];
   String palavra;

public void ler_lista(){   
    String caminho_arquivo = "C:\\Users\\" + 
    System.getProperty("user.name").toString() + "\\Desktop\\" + "palavras.txt";

    try {
        FileReader leitura_arquivo = new FileReader(caminho_arquivo);

        BufferedReader leitor_arquivo = new BufferedReader(leitura_arquivo);

        String linha = leitor_arquivo.readLine();
        int i = 0;
        while(linha != null) {

            palavras_leitura [i] = linha;

            linha = leitor_arquivo.readLine();
            i = i + 1;
        }

        Random Rand = new Random();
        for(int d = 0; d<4 ; d++) {

         palavra = palavras_leitura[Rand.nextInt(i)];
         palavra_vetor[d] = palavra;  ###Esse aqui###
         set_palavra_vetor(d,palavra);

        }

        separador_palavras(palavra_vetor);
        leitor_arquivo.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e){System.out.println(e.getMessage());} 
}

char palavra_separada[][]=new char[4][20];

public  void separador_palavras(String palavra_vetor[]){  

    int quantidade_char = 0;

    for(int c = 0; c < 4; c++){  

        for(int j = 0; j < palavra_vetor[c].length(); j++){
            System.out.print(c);
            System.out.print(palavra_vetor[c].charAt(j));
            palavra_separada[c][j] = palavra_vetor[c].charAt(j);
        }    

    }
    Interface_lista inter = new Interface_lista();
    inter.tabuleiro();
}
```

tentei fazer um getter mas ele só retornava null

```
public String get_palavra_vetor(int index){
    return palavra_vetor[index];
}
```

Comment: Mas do jeito que está aí, esse `get_palavra_vetor` só vai retornar alguma coisa depois que você tiver chamado a função `ler_lista` pelo menos uma vez. Você está fazendo isso?

Comment: sim,estou chamando o get depois de executar a função ler_lista

Comment: Você está engolindo a exceção. Pode estar acontecendo algum erro de leitura que está deixando o método terminar normalmente mas o vetor não está sendo preenchido. Já depurou para ver se ele está sendo preenchido corretamente pelo método?

Comment: sim, no método separador_palavras eu depuro ele e ele imprime de forma correta as palavras do vetor.

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi.. em sua classe não tem uma função de retorno do tipo  array da variável palavra_vetor preenchida.

tenta assim:

```
public String[] ler_lista() {   
        ...

        try
        {
            FileReader leitura_arquivo = new FileReader(caminho_arquivo);

            BufferedReader leitor_arquivo = new BufferedReader(leitura_arquivo);

            String linha = leitor_arquivo.readLine();
            int i = 0;
            while(linha != null)
            {
                palavras_leitura [i] = linha;

                linha = leitor_arquivo.readLine();
                i = i + 1;

            }
            Random Rand = new Random();
            for(int d = 0; d<4 ; d++)
            {
             palavra = palavras_leitura[Rand.nextInt(i)];
             palavra_vetor[d] = palavra;  //###Esse aqui###

             set_palavra_vetor(d,palavra);
            }
            separador_palavras(palavra_vetor);
            leitor_arquivo.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } 
        return palavra_vetor;
    }
```